# General questions about JavaEE security and JDBC realm authentication with WildFly 8.2

Tags: java, security, authentication, jdbc

I'm studying chapters 47...50 of the [JavaEE 7 tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/) about security, authentication, realms... Server managed authentication is totally new to me, so please be patient.

I created my own JDBC realm (using WildFly 8.2) as described at paragraph 50.3 and with the help of [this beautiful article](http://blog.eisele.net/2015/01/jdbc-realm-wildfly820-primefaces51.html).

I have some general questions, I hope you can help:

1. Once the user is authenticated, I obviously need a way to retrieve his identity from within my application. In 48.3.2 ([Checking Caller Identity Programmatically](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/security-webtier003.htm#JEETT01230)) the `getRemoteUser()` method is presented, but the paragraph also says

   > The security API described in this section should be used only in the
   >   less frequent situations in which the web component methods need to
   >   access the security context information.

   What does it mean? Does it mean that using those methods is some kind of bad practice? Is there any other way to retrieve current user data that I'm missing?
2. What if I would like to perform some operations when user successful logs in? Is there something like a method triggered by the "user logged in" event?
3. JDBC realm authentication implies that user credentials are read and checked by the server, the application doesn't even know the coordinates for the auth-reserved DB. For a "new user sign up", do I have to implement a classic solution via application (accessing auth DB, check if chosen username is already present, inert row in the table...) or is there some server-implemented mechanism that I ignore?